# Not able pass data one component to another component using SharedService in angular?

Tags: angular

Not able pass data one component to another component using SharedService

I have created Shared Service,

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
    myData;
    constructor(){
      this.myData= {};
    }
    setMyData(val: object){

      this.myData= val;
    }
    getMyData(){

      return this.myData;
    }
}
```

I want to pass data 'DialogOverviewExample' component to 'DialogOverviewExampleDialog' component .

```
this.result = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }];
```

the above data  i tried to pass using sharedService but i am not getting the data in DialogOverviewExampleDialog component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['dialog-overview-example.css'],
  providers:  [ SharedService ]
})

export class DialogOverviewExample {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private sharedService: SharedService) {}

    ngOnInit() {

      this.result = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }];

        this.sharedService.setMyData(this.result);

  }

}
```

DialogOverviewExampleDialog  component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
  providers:  [ SharedService ]
})


export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    sharedService: SharedService) 
    { 

      console.log(sharedService.getMyData());
    }



}
```

[here is my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrvej3-lgjimi?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `providers:  [ SharedService ]` in each of your components. **By declaring the service as a provider in each component you're creating a unique singleton service for each component.**

You will either need to provide the service to one parent component or in the module that contains both those components.

This StackBlitz **demonstrates declaring the service as a provider in the module** containing both components  [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-yfxnsx)

This Stack **demonstrates declaring the service as a provider in the parent component** [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-paf4tu)

Comment: I added two StackBlitz demos for you. Check out the answer

Comment: In my case both component in ts file(same page) what can i do for that.here you are using two different ts files

Comment: It looks like from your code `DialogOverviewExample` is your parent component so you could leave the `SharedService` as a provider of that component.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrvej3-m6wtru?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts .getting error No provider for SharedService .help me on this

Comment: Here I just saw you had a StackBlitz in your question: Check out this new Stack of your problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrvej3-cusfjw

Comment: You need to move the service to your module, as your component are sibling components, not parent/children.

Comment: @itsme I forgot to add the access modifier to the service in the your Stack, but I just updated it and everything seems to be working fine. You really should consider putting all your components and services into their own files in the future though. It will save you a lot of headache later down the road

Comment: help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927779/autocomplete-is-not-working-in-angular